# Windows software to recognize/classify faces in pictures without uploading

Tags: windows, open-source, face-recognition

My grandmother passed away,  I would like to pull her pictures out of my local storage, but I have a massive amount of images from the past 18 years..

Is there a software that can recognize/classify faces in pictures stored in local HDD without uploading them or storing them to the web?

If possible to achieve this without development – out of the box software,  or minimal wiring...

Expected output is just list of pictures...

Im running windows

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed and better yet it is available free! There are a number of options but one of the better ones is to use a combination of:

- [Python](https://www.python.org/)
- [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/)
- Deep Learning from [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/)

There is a marvellous tutorial, (with downloadable code), on how to:

1. Detect Faces
2. "Quantify" the faces
3. Train a Support Vector Machine
4. Recognise the faces in Images & Videos

It is on the pyImageSearch blog [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/24/opencv-face-recognition/).

All of the above is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform so will work on Windows, Linux, OS-X *(even Raspberry-Pi)*
- Reasonably easy to customise
- Works 100% locally, once you have installed the components you should be able to disconnect from the internet completely.